# why do i getting 415 status code in angular?

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core, webapi, angular14

i have a select box and input in the client.
with the select have the value of how you want to filter the info
genere, authour etc.
and the search box has the value like the genere name.
i pass an nuber which wiht it ik how should i filter.

when i call the post request from angular service im getting error status 415.
how can i fix the problem ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMzzK.png)
this is my function in the repo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Yvo.png)
this is func in the controller :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQmbM.png)
this is how i call it from the service:

```
filterBooks(filterIndex: number,searchValue: string): Observable<Book[]> {
    return this.http.post<Book[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.url}/FilterBooks/${2}`,"Fantasy");
  }
```

and this is from my ts  fille in  the component:

```
filterBook(filterIndex: number, searchValue: any) {
    this._bookService.filterBooks(filterIndex,searchValue).subscribe(result => {
      this.books = result;
   });
  }
```

i tried to test it in swagger and its works fine but in the client side it crashing.

Comment: Why are you interpolating a number here -> `FilterBooks/${2}`? You have not included enough code in this for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: whats the accepted media type of the Filtered Book service?

Comment: @gmalenko im new to this what do you mean by media type ?

Comment: Do you set `Content-Type` or `Content-Encoding` in the http headers somewhere in the frontend? If you look at the network tab in chrome dev tools you should be able to get a bit more information about what content type or encoding is accepted (by looking at the `Accept` or `Accept-Encoding` headers.

Comment: @Antoniossss yes i did bother but i dont understand what is the difference between this request and the other i have that works fine.  im new and i have a college project they didnt teah us how to fix this kind of bugs and i dont realy understand why i get it.

Comment: @ShamPooSham hey , this is my accept : application/json, text/plain, */* and this is accept-encoding : gzip, deflate, br but i dont realy understand the problem, because im sending here string as body parameter and its saying in accept text.

Comment: Accept and Accept-encoding are about what content-types and content-encodings are accepted in the request headers, not about the body format. That's why I asked you if you have those set in your http headers in the frontend.